# Logging in Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have created a .net 2.1 core mvc  and now ready to host it on Azure WebApp.
I am yet to finalize logging.

https://stackify.com/azure-app-service-log-files/

I read above link and found the below snapshot to configure Application logging and Web Server logging. 
[image]

however in my WebApp all I can see is:

[image]

Is this due to my app service plan? 
How do I configure Application logging and Web server logging?

Comment: Is it on a Linux App Service Plan?

Comment: Hi MahHem, try clicking on the Log Streams blade after that click on the Diagnostics logs blade. Do you see the web server logging option now?

Comment: marked answer @NancyXiong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's due to the app service plan. Just check the app on a basic Linux service plan on my side. It's the same as you. Once you click the **Application Logging(filesystem)** `on`, (This setting turns itself `off` after 12 hours), then save it and go back another page or refresh the current page, you will see the **web server logging**. Also, I found this UI always jumps to the previous page like you(without web server logging), after a while, you click another page, this will jump back.

[image]

Moreover, you could check the `Log Stream` to have the ability to see logging information in real-time (or as close to it as possible). Refer to the blog about [Azure Tips and Tricks Part 30 - Working with Log Stream and Azure App Services.](https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks30/)

It's likely a UI bug in the Azure portal. If you want to improve this, you could request [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: The setting is now under App Service logs: Azure -> App Service -> App Service logs -> Application Logging (Filesystem)